# How can you timeout a request from newman CLI

Tags: postman-collection-runner, newman

I have a test suite in Postman and for a request it waits for a specific status in the response body.

I have created a loop through to trigger the request each time until that status field is updated with the expected flag.

The problem is that there is a risk I might go into an infinite loop in case the process gets stuck and when the test runs in the pipelines it will retrigger the same request until someone cancels the pipeline or the pipeline task eventually timesout.

I want to be able to fail a test or collection if it takes x amount of time to run but the --timeout set in the CLI it's not taken into account when running through AzureDevops Pipelines.

Any solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried --timeout-script?

You can find all the Newman command options here - [Newman Command Options](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/newman-options/).

[Newman Request Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwQqG.png)